# How to check remotely the remoted logged in users on a computer, using WMIC?

Tags: remote-desktop, login, user-accounts

I would like to know if it is posible to get the current usernames of remotely logged in users on a computer? From windows cmd?

Kind of:
WMIC /NODE:ComputerName ComputerSystem Get Username

This command works, but gives the users logged in locally to ComputerName. Not the ones who are remotely logged in.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe duplicate with this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/32633/how-to-check-who-is-currently-logged-on-to-windows-workstation-from-command-line

Comment: I don't think so, because as I said the command used in this post gives the usernames logged in locally. I am looking for knowing the users logged in remotely (if possible to do so).

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: It is Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I use this one for my environment, modified slightly to just pull the filter of only the computers I want.  It came out sometime last year I think...works well enough for me on 2008 R2.  Haven't tested it on 2012 though.  I just have it scheduled to run daily.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-script-to-Find-d2ba4252

```
# Import the Active Directory module for the Get-ADComputer CmdLet 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

# Get today's date for the report 
$today = Get-Date 

# Setup email parameters 
$subject = "ACTIVE SERVER SESSIONS REPORT - " + $today 
$priority = "Normal" 
$smtpServer = "YourMailServer" 
$emailFrom = "email@yourdomain.com" 
$emailTo = "email@yourdomain.com" 

# Create a fresh variable to collect the results. You can use this to output as desired 
$SessionList = "ACTIVE SERVER SESSIONS REPORT - " + $today + "`n`n" 

# Query Active Directory for computers running a Server operating system 
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*server*"} 

# Loop through the list to query each server for login sessions 
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) { 
    $ServerName = $Server.Name 

    # When running interactively, uncomment the Write-Host line below to show which server is being queried 
    # Write-Host "Querying $ServerName" 

    # Run the qwinsta.exe and parse the output 
    $queryResults = (qwinsta /server:$ServerName | foreach { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+",","))} | ConvertFrom-Csv)  

    # Pull the session information from each instance 
    ForEach ($queryResult in $queryResults) { 
        $RDPUser = $queryResult.USERNAME 
        $sessionType = $queryResult.SESSIONNAME 

        # We only want to display where a "person" is logged in. Otherwise unused sessions show up as USERNAME as a number 
        If (($RDPUser -match "[a-z]") -and ($RDPUser -ne $NULL)) {  
            # When running interactively, uncomment the Write-Host line below to show the output to screen 
            # Write-Host $ServerName logged in by $RDPUser on $sessionType 
            $SessionList = $SessionList + "`n`n" + $ServerName + " logged in by " + $RDPUser + " on " + $sessionType 
        } 
    } 
} 

# Send the report email 
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -Subject $subject -Body $SessionList -SmtpServer $smtpServer -From $emailFrom -Priority $priority 

# When running interactively, uncomment the Write-Host line below to see the full list on screen 
$SessionList
```

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone else is throwing in their hat on this one, I guess I might as well too.

I *have* been using what @TheCleaner suggested with the qwinsta.exe to monitor active users on Terminal Servers but that only outputs in text.

But I've recently discovered the Win32_UserProfile class which is very promising as I can now output in objects to use in PS.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Profile -ComputerName $Name -Filter "Loaded='True'" | Foreach {$_.LocalPath}
```

**Note: You may need to filter some "Loaded" Profiles by discarding all results in which the $_.LocalPath value is not in the C:\Users folder.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to run from cmd ... I use an awesome little util called NetScan to do this for me.

[NetScan Link](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner)

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to enumerate the instances of EXPLORER.EXE running on the remote host.  Then just pull the owning user.

Example PS command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" -ComputerName "REMOTECOMPUTER" | ForEach-Object{ "{0}\{1}" -f $_.GetOwner().Domain, $_.GetOwner().User }
```

Comment: This implies they have explorer.exe running. This wouldn't be the case of they were remoted in via command line or some other way.